# Explicitly wait for X elements to be visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to wait for a certain numbers of elements to be visible on the page.

For this, I'm using:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout.getValueInSec());  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
```

Although timeout is long enough, this method returns less elements than I see and expect (2 of 6 in this concrete case). It probably returns as soon as it finds 2 elements, before the rest of them are there.

Is there a way to tell Selenium driver to wait for X elements?
Something like:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNElementsLocatedBy(6, locator));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to make a *custom [Expected Condition](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#151)* for your specific requirement:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>> visibilityOfNElementsLocatedBy(
      final By locator, final int elementsCount) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>>() {
      @Override
      public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
        List<WebElement> elements = findElements(locator, driver);

        // KEY is here - we are "failing" the expected condition 
        // if there are less than elementsCount elements
        if (elements.size() < elementsCount) {
          return null;
        }

        for(WebElement element : elements){
          if(!element.isDisplayed()){
            return null;
          }
        }
        return elements;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "visibility of N elements located by " + locator;
      }
    };
  }
```

Usage:

```
wait.until(visibilityOfNElementsLocatedBy(locator, 6));
```

Comment: I think this will work the same way as my example. findElements() does not wait and would return the CURENTLY displayed elements (2 of 6 in my case). I need a way to somwhow consider X in waiting function.

Comment: @Aleks try it out first please. The key is this `elements.size() != elementsCount` check that (if failed) would let selenium know that it needs to continue calling the condition until it does not return `null`.

Comment: You were right, it works. I did not understand that part, clearly have a lot to learn. :) Thanks!